# Can I change the Panel Parameter in the Google API buildingInsights?

Tags: google-maps, google-solar-api

**Issue with Google Solar API: Modifying Panel Parameters**

I've recently started using the Google Solar API for my project and I'm facing a challenge when it comes to modifying panel parameters. Specifically, I'd like to adjust the following values:

```
 "panelCapacityWatts": 250,
 "panelHeightMeters": 1.65,
 "panelWidthMeters": 0.992,
 "panelLifetimeYears": 20,
```

These parameters are returned by the API, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify them to achieve more precise results.

Does anyone have experience with how to adjust these values within the Google Solar API, or is there a specific method or documentation that I might have overlooked? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

I attempted to modify the panel parameters provided by the Google Solar API by updating the following values in my code:

- panelWidthMeters
- panelHeightMeters

but got this:

```
`{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"panelWidthMeters\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'panelWidthMeters' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"panelHeightMeters\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'panelHeightMeters' could not be found in request message.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
                "fieldViolations": [
                    {
                        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"panelWidthMeters\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'panelWidthMeters' could not be found in request message."
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"panelHeightMeters\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'panelHeightMeters' could not be found in request message."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}`
```

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to modify these parameters at the moment. the api is fairly new and I agree that it would be nice to be able to set these values manually but hopefully they will add these capabilities in the future.